# How can I initialize one model in another model's controller action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view

I created a web-app in Asp.net MVC and it has an order action. I have these two models for Order

```
 public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset OrderTime { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Order")]
        public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

and for OrderDetail

```
public class OrderDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
        public Menu Menu { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

And I created tables for them.
Also I created a controller for Order. It contains Index and Details actions. Index acction shows the list of order and every order has its own Detail link which should contain information of Order and related OrderDetail

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order order = db.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }
```

And the problem is that OrderDetails is null. Can you suggest me how I can initialize OrderDetail in Details action?

Comment: @Sir Rufo should i edit Details action method?

Comment: @Sir Rufo I debugged the method and it shows me that OrderDetail is null

Comment: @Sir Rufo how can I initialize OrderDetails in this method?

Comment: @Sir Rufo  Can you help to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell EntityFramework which navigation properties you want to include.

```
Order order = db.Orders
    .Where( o => o.Id == id )
    .Include( o => o.OrderDetails )
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

But you cannot use Find method any more

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help for showing items, but in action OrderDetails value changed to "Count = 0"

Comment: Well then there are no details stored for that order

Comment: But remember: Your question is why the OrderDetails property is null. If you have another question feel free to ask another question.

Comment: no, it has realted data in there. I saw other order's details too, it's the same. It doesn't show nothing

Comment: But what does Count=0 mean?

Comment: if it means emptydata then it didn't help

Comment: I did not have access to your data, so I do not know what it is in your database, so I cannot answer what is going on with your data. I know how to tell EF to load the navigation properties - and it does, because OrderDetails is not null anymore as you state. And that was the question here.